# Unable to save the file correctly

Tags: python-3.x, file

I have a text file contains a text about a story and I want to find a word "like" and get the next word after it and call a function to find synonyms for that word. here is my code:

```
file = 'File1.txt'
with open(file, 'r') as open_file:
    read_file = open_file.readlines()
    output_lines = []        

for line in read_file:
    words = line.split()
    for u, word in enumerate(words):
        if 'like' == word:
            next_word = words[u + 1]
            find_synonymous(next_word )

    output_lines.append(' '.join(words))
    with open(file, 'w') as open_file:
        open_file.write(' '.join(words))
```

my only problem I think in the text itself, because when I write one sentence including the word (like) it works( `for example 'I like movies'`). but when I have a file contains a lot of sentences and run the code it deletes all text. can anyone know where could be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of problems. `find_synonymous(next_word )` doesn't replace the word in the list, so at best you will get the original text back. You do `open(file, 'w')` inside the `for` loop, so the file is overwritten for each line. `next_word = words[u + 1]` will raise an index error if `like` happens to be the last word on the line and you don't handle the case where the thing that is liked continues on the next line.

In this example, I track an "is_liked" state. If a word is in the like state, it is converted. That way you can handle sentences that are split across lines and don't have to worry about index errors. The list is written to the file outside the loop.

```
file = 'File1.txt'
with open(file, 'r') as open_file:
    read_file = open_file.readlines()

output_lines = []        
is_liked = False

for line in read_file:
    words = line.split()
    for u, word in enumerate(words):
        if is_liked:
            words[u] = find_synonymous(word)
            is_liked = False
        else:
            is_liked = 'like' == word
    output_lines.append(' '.join(words) + '\n')

with open(file, 'w') as open_file:
    open_file.writelines(output_lines)
```